# Error: waiting for creation of Cluster (Terraform)

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

I want to create a AKS cluster with Terraform using the aks module : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest

When I run `terraform apply`, I can see that **my aks cluster is actually created in my azure subscription**, but I get the following error message :

`Error: waiting for creation of Cluster: (Managed Cluster Name "aks" / Resource Group "RG"): Code="ProvisioningControlPlaneError" Message="AKS encountered an internal error while attempting the requested Creating operation. AKS will continuously retry the requested operation until successful or a retry timeout is hit. Check back to see if the operation requires resubmission.`

Azure tells me that my cluster is in failed state, then after a couple minutes the status turns into an "updating" state.

Problem is, no node is being created in my cluster, and my *terraform.tfstate* file does not get updated with the cluster (even if it has actually been created).

**How can I avoid my aks cluster to be created in that failed state ?**

Comment: Can you provide more information about the deployment? Are you using CNI, haave you opened required ports on any firewall/nsg on the vnet/subnet? Are you using UDR? The reason your tfstate isn't getting updated is because the cluster is not in succeeded deployment state, hence terraform considers it not being deployed.